# File Reading and Processing

Tags: java

I am stuck on how I should go about reading/processing a file.

Example File:

```
  2

  cow
  moo
  black
  and white very fast

  pig
  pink
  very slow
```

The 2 indicates the number of entries in the file. Blank line. Then the name of the object and two lines of characteristics.

Basically I'm confused as the best way to go about reading the input line by line and processing it so I can create the designated object.

I was thinking that I can create an arraylist and then go from there but I don't know how the blank line delimiters would be taken. And since the number of elements could be different for every file, I'm unsure how to take that into account.

Comment: Just use a Scanner/BufferedReader, since you know the structure of the file.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your issue is more on a conceptual level than a syntax level so I will try to answer at that level.

First I don't think the number at the start is required, but you can use it to check that you are on track after the fact.

I think you should create a class that describes your objects, lets call it the "Animal" class for reference.  The constructor should take an array list that contains just the subset of lines relevant to one particular animal (the one you are instantiating).  The properties for the class should be whatever you require (e.g. name, etc..).

So in pseudo-code:

prep the array list:

```
-read each line of file into arraylist
```

consume the arraylist:

```
-read and save off the number of entries for checking later
-read and ignore the first blank line
-read line by line into another arraylist until the next blank line, pass your new array list to the constructor for your Animal class and then repeat this until you hit the end of file (making sure to construct the final object as well).
```

"Animal" Constructor:

```
-Set the first entry in the arrayList passed to constructor as the animals Name.
-Set remaining properties as required....
```

As you create animals you can store them in some array as well and at the end you can validate that you created the correct number with the value you stored off at the start.